# How to use a image instead of activity indicator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uiimage, ios-4.2

in my app when i click on refresh button, an activity indicator appears. and when tableView is refreshed then it disappears. i want to use a image instead of that activity indicator in such a way that when i click on refresh that image ll come on the whole screen and when view ll b refreshed it ll disappear. how can i do that? thanx in advance

Comment: Wanna share the code that shows the activity indicator?

Comment: Sorry, have to ask out of curiosity here, what on earth does 'll' (two lower case letter Ls) mean? Is it an acronym I've not heard before?

Comment: What does 'full screen' mean? Everyting, including the status bar area? Everything except status bar area? Only the current view, not including any Apple container UI element such as UINavigationController or UITabController etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is add a "cover page" view over your current view.

These usually work best if you set the alpha to about 50%.

Hitting the button you can call `addSubview:coverPage` where you init coverPage somewhere with the right attributes.

If you want, cover page can have it's own spinners or labels if necessary.

after your refresh completes, just call `[coverPage removeFromSuperview]` to dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

`UIActivityIndicatorView` is the spinning thing that is the default busy indicator. It inherits from UIView. If you subclass it and have your own `drawRect:` implementation you should be able to draw any image you like in place of the spinning bars.

Comment: But then you'll have an image the same size as the bounds of the UIActivityIndicatorView. The OP wants something covering the whole screen.

Comment: I think you can cover the screen if clipsToBounds is set in appropriate places (the containing views).